# How to worship a shiva linga?

Tags: shiva, worship, shiva-lingam

How does one practice to worship shiva linga in house? What are the specific days and events which are essential to be performed, and do we have to put milk,curd,honey and ghee each week to maintain the shivalinga?

Comment: Even Bilva leaf and water are adequate in a house Pooja. Other materials are used more in temples.